# Delay in getting message from Microsoft Message Queue

Tags: msmq

There is a delay of 8 to 9 minutes in receiving the message in user's machine from a server's MSMQ. There is no blocks in network connectivity. How to find the root cause of the issue. Can any one help. 
It is happening in many machines.Initially, there is no delay in receiving the messages from MSMQ.

Updates:
There are two servers - server 1 and server 2. Message sending from server 1 is getting delayed. There is no delay if the message is sent from server 2. What we need to check from server end? Can any one help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delay in receiving the message from server to user machine via MSMQ is resolved.
Added registry keys DeferFirstConnectAttempt and WaitTime. These two keys resolved the latency issue.